# Why is my Windows user directory littered with .inf and .sys files?

Tags: file-management, inf

I've noticed quite an accumulation of files in my base users directory on Windows Vista (C:\Users\username).  I really hate having files littered across my hard drive unnecessarily.

Some of them seem to be related to Motorola--I have a Motorola RAZR V3m that I connect to my computer via USB.  Here's a sampling of the file names:

- 1236237042-oem13.inf
- MCCI_BUS.INF
- MCCI_MDM.INF
- MCCI_SDM.INF
- mqdmbus.sys
- mqdmcmnt.sys
- USB_CMCS_2000.INF
- USB_MOT_A1000.INF
- USB_MOT_BRIT.INF
- USBMOT2000.INF
- usbsermpt.sys

**How did these files get here and are they safe to delete?**

Answer (score 1):

These files are for the Motorola phone:

- mqdmbus.sys
- mqdmcmnt.sys
- USB_CMCS_2000.INF
- USB_MOT_A1000.INF
- USB_MOT_BRIT.INF
- USBMOT2000.INF
- usbsermpt.sys

And these seem to be from [Sealthbot](http://www.stealthbot.net/board/):

- 1236237042-oem13.inf
- MCCI_BUS.INF
- MCCI_MDM.INF
- MCCI_SDM.INF

Whether or not you still use these programs will determine if you should delete them.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how Vista installs things. If you have a lot of USB devices, you will have a lot of those files.